# JNDI look up is failing with in java.util.TimerTask

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, java-5

```
public class ReferenceDataTimer extends TimerTask
{
   private static ReferenceDataTimer refDataTimerTask = new ReferenceDataTimer();
   private Timer refDataTimer = null;
   public void start()
   {
        refDataTimer = new Timer();
        refDataTimer.schedule(refDataTimerTask, DELAY, refreshTime*PERIOD);
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
    // Get DB connection using 
    // InitialContext lookup 
    // using resource reference             

    => This is where it is failing. lookup is not working from this run() method of timer task.

    // Then load the data to cache

   }
}

public class ReferenceDataManager implements ServletContextListener {
 // Invoking ReferenceDataTimer -> start() method.
}
```

And Im getting JNDI lookup error while getting data source Connection from server context using a resource reference. Please note that look up IS WORKING if I don't use `TimerTask`.

> javax.naming.ConfigurationException: A JNDI operation on a "java:" name cannot be     completed because the server runtime is not able to associate the operation's thread with any J2EE application component. This condition can occur when the JNDI client using the "java:" name is not executed on the thread of a server application request.  Make sure that a J2EE application does not execute JNDI operations on "java:" names within static code blocks or in threads created by that J2EE application. Such code does not necessarily run on the thread of a server application request and therefore is not supported by JNDI operations on "java:" names.

Can any one please suggest? If it is not possible to get resource (available in server context) with in `java.util.Timer` task `run()` method then please suggest an alternative.
I even tried with `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService` -> `scheduleAtFixedRate` but in vain.

Comment: The question is tagged with "java-ee", but the JNDI call originates from a `ServletContextListener`: So is it "servlet-container-only" or "EJB features are fine" as well? How does the JNDI name look like`? Which application server? Please show the full code of `run`.

Comment: It is a web application deployed in WebSphere application server. Jndi name is 'jdbc/ctc' and I'm accessing it via a resource-reference which is mapped in web.xml of my web application. Iam worrying to apply the solution given by @isnot2bad below. It may be correct but please let me know if I can manage with any other  solution rather than creating an Enter Prise bean with TimerService call back events.

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem using JBoss 7 using the global JNDI directly (= without resource-ref mapping in web.xml). So try to use a *global JNDI name* to lookup the data source. Again, add the source of `run()` which does the lookup, add the resource mapping, and possibly a screenshot of the data source configuration to your question.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. As I said even Im also not getting any issue if I use global JNDI name. But using JNDI name directly in the code is tightly coupled to server configuration. Hence Im not allowed to do this :-(

Comment: But you *are* allowed to create *unmanaged* threads? I have never seen any data center which really uses the additional redirection. Anyway in your case, just use a system property, context-param or a separate .properties file to configure the global JNDI name, so that the data center can change the value of it (and I bet they will never change it).

Comment: Sure Bery :-) Will give a try as u said on tomorrow. Thanks for ur prompt reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `TimerTask` in an EJB application as this will create and start a custom `Thread` which is not allowed in a Java EE environment.

Instead, use the `TimerService`. It is part of the Java EE standard.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried as u suggested. I've created javax.ejb.TimerService but getting same exception :-( Can u suggest any other solution?